# How to set content type for WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request to an external service using `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler`, and I am having a lot of trouble getting the `Content-Type` header set for the outbound request. By default it sets the `Content-Type` to `x-java-serialized-object`, but the service I'm hitting only accepts `application/json`. The only way around this I have found so far is to pass in a custom `HeaderMapper`:

```
webFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.setHeaderMapper(object : HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> {
        override fun toHeaders(source: HttpHeaders): MutableMap<String, Any> {
            return mutableMapOf()
        }

        override fun fromHeaders(headers: MessageHeaders, target: HttpHeaders) {
            target.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        }

    })
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper()` has an ability to map a:

```
case "contenttype": // Lower case for MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE
            setContentType(target, value);
```

to the `Content-Type` HTTP header. So, you can try to set that `MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE` message header upstream before sending the message to this `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler`.

That `x-java-serialized-object` is not a standard `MimeType`, so I guess you have a configuration like `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.setExtractPayload(false)`, which means try to send the whole `Message<?>` over HTTP. Not sure if that is what you want to achieve because the `Message<?>` is not fully JSON compatible...